# Is there a common saying in English that means "It's just business, I don't feel any shame"

Tags: phrases, translation, popular-refrains, proverb-requests

In [Gujarati language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gujarati_language) there is a saying which literally means "no shame in business".

It is used in a context where one has to do something unpleasant (or immoral) for the sake of their business (business as in profession). 
When criticized for doing what they do, they use this phrase to justify their actions, they do it for the sake of their business and don't feel any shame or regret.

Is there a common saying in English which conveys the same? If so and if possible can you provide some earliest references of its use.

Comment: One similar but not identical one is ***to make an omelette, you have to break a few eggs***.

Comment: @DanBron  Good call.

Comment: *Greed is good.* – Wall Street, 1987

Comment: @Amit How is it identical when it doesn't mention or even necessarily refer to business dealings? There are internet examples referring to biting the bullet in sport, legal proceedings, and redecorating one's bedroom.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth as you are saying, you are making your point. I said It is Identical because it is carrying exactly same sense (meaning).

Comment: But it obviously doesn't. Playing for the school rugby team and painting your room lilac have no direct connection with business.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth As I said I got your point and yes I didn't think that way at first place!

Comment: "You do what you have to do."

Comment: This is a funny question, because that's exactly what "It's just business" means.

Comment: It's worth noting that, while there are many idioms along these lines, it is increasingly unlikely to be used as a justification for an immoral work ethic.

Comment: @AJFaraday Actually I too have noticed that. Each answer is required some amount of research (mostly answer itself provides external sources) for the context it is being used.

Comment: @Amit: Just out of curiosity, what is that Gujarati saying?

Comment: @Jay "ધંધા માં શરમ નહિ : No shame in business"

Comment: The Gujarati phrase is not one that is used in English, but it in an appropriate context, it would be perfectly well understood and may be more suitable than any of the suggested alternatives. It may be that the best answer is simply to use that.

Comment: @Simba I'm sorry, I didn't get your last comment here. can you please explain ?

Comment: @Amit - I mean that although the phrase "no shame in business" isn't a known saying in English, it could be used in exactly that form and people would understand what you meant, if the context was clear. Therefore, it may be sufficient to use this phrase exactly as you stated it; you may not need to find an equivalent English idiom.

Comment: @Simba yeah, you have a point here. At the end, conveying what we mean is the only thing what matters.

Comment: As a side note, it would be interesting to learn if the phrase is frequently used as justification in Gujarati?

Comment: @Gnudiff yes, it is very common saying here in this region (Gujarat state of India) where I am living!

Comment: @Amit to be honest, sounds extremely unappealing.

Comment: @JessRiedel but doesn't that signal that it may not be what I wanted to do, but I had to.

Comment: @mathreadler : I think "you do what you gotta do" implies that *something* about the action is undesirable, including shameful or unpleasant, as requested by Amit.  This phrase could be used by someone unhappy to be moving garbage or by someone embarrassed to be a used-car salesman (even if they enjoy sales).

Comment: @JessRiedel your provided examples are more suitable for "Dignity of labour" , here context is something like, he is 'feeling no shame' in sending legal notice to his best friend/family member over not repaying his debt. (this matter, he could have solved by mutual understanding and talking, but he chose unexpected and somewhat sentiment (of his friend or family) hurting way.)

Comment: Amit, I cannot understand the sentiment you're trying to express, but I can say that "you do what you gotta do" is very distinct from the inherent dignity of honest labor. The latter disputes any shamefulness while the former is simply not bothered by it.

Comment: @JessRiedel I have upvoted on your first suggesting comment "you do what you gotta do". I do agree with you on this phrase. I was talking about your provided example on last comment! and Sentiments : if one's brother ruthlessly drag him to court and then to the cell (for such matter which could have resolved peacefully) then he must feel sad and kind of trust broken.

Answer (score 115, accepted):

> "Nothing personal, it's just business."

Coined by Otto "Abbadabba" Berman an accountant for the Mafia in early 1900’s in New York. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Otto_Berman)

In The Godfather movie, Michael Corleone likewise says: *It's not personal. It's strictly business.*
See [YouTube](https://youtube.com/watch?v=Bo7zkd0kRS4)

Comment: I think the meaning of this phrase in English is close to, but importantly different than, what Amit is asking.  The English phrase is not intended to suggest the speaker is free from shame, just that the action isn't emotional. With [higher sound quality](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0qvpcfYFHcw), the exact line is "It's not personal, [Sonny](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sonny_Corleone). It's strictly business."  Here, Michael Corleone is speaking to his brother and is assuring him that Michael's violent plan is motivated by business and not a personal vendetta.

Comment: In other words, you might use the phrase "Nothing personal, it's just business" when buying from a cheaper supplier instead of your friend (who happens to be a competing supplier and is more expensive).  On the other hand, you would not use this phrase if you were humiliating yourself to win a contract, but it sounds from Amit's description like you *would* use the Gujarati phrase in that case.

Comment: Tom Hanks says it to Meg Ryan in _You've Got Mail_.  [She takes exception to it ...](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5DN57r3-xzE)  (She gets the last laugh though: Consider what happened to Borders and what's coming for Barnes&Noble.)  I do believe though that Tom is feeling shame ... so I think @JessRiedel is right in comments above.

Comment: Or maybe it can be used both in contexts where shame is present, and where it isn't, and you have to figure out which situation you're in by non-verbal cues.

Comment: In my opinion, the Gujarati phrase (~"You do what you have to do") and "Nothing personal, it's just business" are logically distinct.  That means there are situations where one and not the other is sensible, but also situations where both or neither are.  When both are sensible, the speaker would just use the one that expresses what they want to say.

Comment: This is a recurring theme in _the Godfather_. When Tessio (who was planning to betray Michael) is rumbled, he says to Tom Hagen, "Tell Michael it was only business..." https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RIJIXMX2zw8

Comment: There is another one in Godfather 2, "This is the business we have chosen ..".

Answer (score 61):

**business is business**

In [The Free Dictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/business+is+business):

> A phrase that emphasizes business decisions as completely separate from emotions or personal issues.

In [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/business%20is%20business):

> used to say that in order for a business to be successful it is necessary to do things that may hurt or upset people

Exactly how "immoral" an action can be and still be covered by these sayings is perhaps a question for a different venue.

Comment: Excellent!! this is certainly a pin pointed answer. As accurate as selected answer! in fact more preferable in general talk! thank you.

Comment: @Amit Please consider accepting the answer with the check mark if you think it satisfied your request the most! :)

Comment: @Ian I have already accepted one answer here. long before this answer was even posted.

Comment: @Amit Whoops, missed that!

Comment: @Amit It's customary to wait at least 24 hours before accepting an answer, because half of the globe may be asleep when you first post.

Comment: @Amit fwiw you can change accepted answer if you want

Comment: Accept the *best* answer, when it was posted is irrelevant

Answer (score 47):

"All is fair in love and war."

Like the Gujarati phrase as described in the question, this makes the specific claim that ethics don't apply when certain vital interests are at stake for the speaker.

I think it is frequently said in the context of business.

Here's an example:

> They say that all is fair in love and war – and most people extend that saying through to business.
>   —[Ben Kepes, *All's Fair in Love, War and Business*, October 14, 2008](https://www.cloudave.com/2811/alls-fair-in-love-war-and-business/)

And here's a dictionary entry (Merriam-Webster):

> [Definition of **all's fair in love and war**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/all's%20fair%20in%20love%20and%20war)
>   —used to describe a situation in which people do not follow the usual rules of behavior and do things that are normally considered unfair • Sure, it was underhanded to steal his customers, but *all's fair in love and war*.

And another (TheFreeDictionary.Com):

> [**all is fair in love and war**](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/all%27s+fair+in+love+and+war)
>   Otherwise questionable actions are acceptable under extenuating circumstances. Often written as "all's fair in love and war." *A: "I can't believe you took credit for my idea just so you would look good to the boss!" B: "Come on, all is fair in love and war!"*

Comment: This carries a certain connotation of ruthlessness, in my experience. Other suggestions are more neutral, though I'm not sure which more accurately reflects the Gujarati phrase.

Comment: I think this matches very well the gist of the Gujarati phrase as described here--the connotations of "no regrets" and self-justification, in particular, seem like a good fit. FYI, I've added text from your links; this is considered best practice here, so that folks don't have to click away from the site to see your point and also in case of link rot. If I've pulled the wrong quotes or otherwise mischaracterized your intent, please feel free to edit further or roll back.

Comment: Thanks 1006a, on all counts. You showed me the way, and the why, and you  quoted the parts I think justify my answer.

Comment: @1006a there is another phrase in [Urdu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urdu) which is literally translated and generally accepted (*in Hindi - "प्यार और जंग में सब जायज है : Everything is fair in love and war" and some other regional languages of India*) from this "all is fair in love and war" and sometimes they add business too. Phrase I asked about is almost similar but still having little different applications. *I need to do more research on difference but one thing I can sense "all is fair in love and war"  is used for more intense action.*

Answer (score 33):

As suggested by Dan Bron, "**you've got to crack a few eggs to make an omelette**" may fit. We use it to imply that to achieve a purpose, something must be sacrificed. (in this case, principles, moral norms, and the like.

> In order to achieve something, it is inevitable that some mistakes are made or some sacrifices occur. [*Wiktionary*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/you%27ve_got_to_crack_a_few_eggs_to_make_an_omelette)

Comment: It's polite to convert someone else's suggestion to a Community Wiki. Not that this is all that close.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I disagree. Centaurus took the time and effort to actually post as an answer.  Posting an answer as a comment does not give you any ownership over it.

Comment: I agree with @Kat. If I’d wanted credit for an answer, I’d have posted an answer. I already upvoted this. Though I think it’d be improved if the actual phrase being suggested were gilded or otherwise set apart and made more obvious.

Answer (score 19):

Don’t know how common it might be, but here’s a phrase from a relatively
recent American novel:

*I’ve got to make a living.*

Source: Fannie Flagg, *Fried Green Tomatoes at the Whistle Stop Cafe*.
Context: A white business owner in small-town Alabama, decades before
the Civil Rights Movement, is explaining to an African-American boy why
she can’t let him sit at a table in her cafe, even though she has no
personal objections. “There’s [a bunch in town](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ku_Klux_Klan) that would burn me down in
a minute, and I’ve got to make a living.”

This particular example is not quite on point for the question, however,
as the speaker does regret the necessity, and resists it as much as she
can: she serves African-American customers out the back door, stands up
to an authority figure who criticizes her doing so, and eventually
starts giving them a discount.

Comment: With variants like "It's a living" and "it pays the bills"/"whatever pays the bills".

Comment: It's idiomatic. No worries about how common it is. +1

Comment: @JKreft I've only ever seen those expressions in the sense of the speaker is willing to make any effort to keep food on the table, rather than as a acknowledgement of compromising morals  in order to get ahead in business. Those expressions are indicative of moral fortitude and stamina in the face of adversity whilst the OP's request is, loosely, about willingness to compromise ruthlessly for money. They are quite antithetical IMO.

Comment: @pbhj They're commonly used to cover any question about a person's profession, often as a way to shut the conversation down instead of going into motivations, morality, etc.

Comment: That could mean the person does still feel shame though just that does not see any other/better way to act.

Answer (score 17):

It's a dirty job but someone's got to do it.

Comment: I cannot recall where I've heard this. Can you please provide me some references!

Comment: @amit; http://www.metrolyrics.com/we-care-a-lot-lyrics-faith-no-more.html

Comment: @Amit Maybe it reminds you of the TV series? [Dirty Jobs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirty_Jobs) and [Somebody's gotta do it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Somebody%27s_Gotta_Do_It), presented by the same person and the second airing a few years after the first had finished.

Comment: Did you [Google the phrase](https://www.google.com/search?q=It%27s+a+dirty+job+but+someone%27s+got+to+do+it.)? It could be anywhere...

Comment: This is a really common saying I think, may be a regionally specific phrase though.

Answer (score 14):

***The end justifies the means.*** (Thanks [rahul](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/1635/rahul).)

This proverbial (and controversial) observation dates from ancient times, but in English it was first recorded only in 1583, in the Niccolo Machiavelli's book [The Prince](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Prince).

See [The Free Dictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/the+end+justifies+the+means), and the [discussion about its meaning](https://www.answers.com/Q/What_does_the_end_justifies_the_means_mean).

Comment: This does not seem to be a common saying. Far more common is "the end justifies the means".

Comment: As a note, "the purpose..." sounds like a bad two-way translation of the idiom.

Comment: It should be noted that The Prince was written in Italian in the 16th century.

Comment: According to Petrina’s *Machiavelli in the British Isles*, the first English translations (anonymous manuscripts) were seen around the 1580s, with the first printed translation being published in 1640.

Comment: When said, this carries more of an implication of intentionally aggressive than uncaring behaviour - which is ironic given what the actual sentence says.

Answer (score 11):

For a lower-level version of this, you'll also hear "I'm just doing my job." Or "That's the job." or similar statements.

"Just following orders" also shows up in contexts where the organization or person giving the orders (police, military, religious organization) is presumed to have a moral imperative to be able to do things without shame that would otherwise be immoral.

Comment: "I put in my two week notice," or "This 'job' sucks."

Comment: Related Wikipedia article: [Superior orders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superior_orders)

Comment: @BobJarvis True, but irrelevant. He was asking for an expression that would express the sentiment, not one that justifies the action.

Answer (score 11):

Don't hate the player, hate the game. Listed by [Wikitionary.](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/don%27t_hate_the_player,_hate_the_game)

Comment: Please add a source to support your answer.

Answer (score 10):

> Where no oxen are, the crib is clean: but much increase is by the strength of the ox.

[Proverbs 14:4](http://textusreceptusbibles.com/Interlinear/20014004)

The proverb (as I have heard it and used it) is usually shortened to 'Where no oxen are, the crib is clean' or can even be used in a yet more succinct version 'where no oxen are ...'.

Comment: I would want to know more about it. can you please share some more and detailed references!

Comment: @Amit  The quote is from the Book of Proverbs which is a collection of proverbs. There is no context; it is a collection. The proverb states that without oxen, the stable is clean and tidy and neat. But productive work means making a mess.

Comment: @Amit Given that the source is the Book of Proverbs which forms part of the bible, this is more a Judeo-Christian saying than specifically an English language one. You wouldn't hear it much in London where I am from. But it's probably well known in the Bible Belt area of the United States.

Comment: lol. Appropriate and straightforward, but not particularly well known.

Comment: In the Hebrew bible the phrase is a bit different. The first appearance of "Oxen" is actually a word meaning "Oxen that were trained for work". Most interpretations (from centuries ago) speak about how humans have to work and train hard to acquire education. If they don't (where no oxen are) there will be no wisdom (the crib is clean). But if they work and train hard to acquire education, the food piles (wisdom) will be full - even though those animals eat, their work produces overall more food than they eat (much increase...). I.e. - the investment in education pays off.

Comment: @AmitA The word used in Proverbs 14:4 is  אֲ֭לָפִים, _alaphim_ [Strong 504](http://biblehub.com/hebrew/504.htm). Strong says it means 'yoked' which could refer to a family responsibility but the context of a stable indicates that yoked oxen are in view.

Comment: I’m referring to Rashi (died 1105), Gersonides (died 1344), and Malbim (died 1879) - all rabbis who interpreted the original Hebrew text. Indeed, the English word yoked suggests a similar context. I’m not sure if your intent was also to communicate that the text should only be read literally. When we interpret the Bible, we do not lock down on one meaning, as Hebrew words often have multiple meanings. We also do not interpret it literally, as the text works in multiple layers. This is especially true about Proverbs - a book whose purpose is to contain lessons and moral values.

Comment: @AmitA Veering off-topic, I'm afraid. Your comments are more suitable to Bible Hermeneutics but even there I would disagree with you and I would be quoting BDB, Strong, Green and Young's Literal.

Comment: As you wish. As a Hebrew native speaker who studied the Bible for 16 years (school + university courses) my point is that if you interpret the Bible, at least the Hebrew text, literally - you are missing the point, and ignoring a plethora of philosophers and interpreters. It’s not wrong, of course, it is just shallow. But, I agree I am off topic, as my arguments do not apply to how one may go about interpreting the English translation and its current usage, even if those deviate from the intent of the original text.

Comment: @AmitA Without any offence whatsoever to yourself, personally, I prefer to follow established authorities (such as the ones I mentioned). Kind Regards.

Comment: None taken. We must come from very different worlds. In the Jewish world of bible interpretation, Strong is insignificant (e.g, the Wikipedia entry on him is not translated to Hebrew). Rashi, on the other hand, has been an authority for almost one millennium. I therefore suggest we leave the word “established” out of the discussion. Again, Strong is accurate in his literal meaning. I can’t say anything about the meaning of the English translation of that phrase. But the widely accepted Hebrew meaning is certainly not literal - the entire book of Proverbs isn’t meant to be read literally.

Answer (score 10):

There is a Latin saying which has been translated to many languages:
Money does not stink.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pecunia_non_olet

Comment: Not a common saying in English.

Comment: There is an English version though, see [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/335619).

Comment: Where there's muck there's brass

Comment: @RedSonja, that's a different meaning. "Where there's muck there's brass" is about people being willing to work hard despite the filth in order to make money, as others aren't willing then the work attracts a higher rate of pay. "Money doesn't stink" is about being morally lax because whilst the manner of acquisition is immoral the money is the same as if it had been acquired by more wholesome means.

Comment: The English idiom is along the lines of "Dirty money spends as well as clean." and "Money doesn't care where it came from/how you earned it."

Answer (score 1):

"There are no friends in business" is a commonly-used phrase derived from Alexandre Dumas “In business, sir, one has no friends, only correspondents. ”

That is, you can shamelessly backstab anyone in business to get a better outcome.

Answer (score 0):

**To punch a/the puppy.**

Source: many office buzzword articles such as [this one](https://www.thinkbusiness.ie/articles/avoid-business-jargon/)
Relatively new, google trends has it popping up regularly only since 2010.

Answer (score -1):

The expression "no shame in business" somewhat reflects the concept of ***dignity of labour***.

Wikipedia:

> **[Dignity of labour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dignity_of_labour)**
>   The dignity of labour, also known as the dignity of work, is the philosophy that all types of jobs are
>   respected equally, and no occupation is considered superior.

Comment: Interestingly there's another saying (in Hindi and accepted in Gujarati) for 'Dignity of labour' which is "कोइ भी घंघा छोटा नहीं होता : No business is smaller (in terms of reputation)". And this line became viral after a bollywood movie staring Shahrukh khan, Raees.

Comment: I think this is the opposite of what's sought. This seeks to dignify and uplift honest work; the OP's phrase is about excusing dishonest, immoral behavior.